# How do I parse snake case fields in a FeignClient response json?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-cloud-feign

I have configured a FeignClient in my spring boot webapp where I'm calling an external api that returns the following object.

```java
public class Issue {

    private Assignee assignee;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
    private Date closedAt;
    private String description;
    private Date dueDate;

    public Assignee getAssignee() {
        return assignee;
    }

    public void setAssignee(Assignee assignee) {
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Date getClosedAt() {
        return closedAt;
    }

    public void setClosedAt(Date closedAt) {
        this.closedAt = closedAt;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (JacksonJson.toJsonString(this));
    }
}
```

The fields `updatedAt`, `createdAt` and `closedAt` are all in snake case. All multi-word fields show up as null. Is there any way of configuring the FeignClient's Jackson parser so that it can process snake case characters? Note, that I cannot change the default Jackson Parser for my spring boot webapp because I myself render json in camel case. I just need to configure this parser on the FeignClient that I'm using to connect to an external REST api.

I have verified that the json response returned from the api call contains valid values in each of these json fields.

Comment: The result remains still the same if for example you use JsonProperty("created_At") over the createdAt field  or it is not possible to add the annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. I created a custom JacksonParser as a Spring Bean.

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class FeignClientDateFormatConfig {

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(customObjectMapper());
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(objectFactory));
    }

    public ObjectMapper customObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

This successfully parses all snake case properties.

Please note that this has a severe limitation. If you have multiple `FeignClients` and only one of them returns snake-case json, then you're out of luck. This overrides the default `FeignClient` config. The only workaround possible with this solution is to move your `FeignClient` calls into a separate microservice so other `FeignClient` calls are not affected.

Comment: In case of various feign clients it's best to exclude this configuration from SpringContext (I do it by creating @ExcludeFromScan annotation) and import solo configuration into @FeignClient(configuration = ...)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I have used `@JsonNaming` annotation, which is available in `jackson-databind:2.11.4` library. In annotation parameter you need to define property naming strategy for json parsing. In our case `PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class` does the trick.
Naming strategy is changed only for the entity under annotation, other places of application are not affected.

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Issue {...}
```